# Frameworks use abstract classes - Factory method

Tags: oop, design-patterns, factory-pattern

From Addison Wesley - Design patterns.

(Factory method)

> Frameworks use abstract classes to define and maintain relationships between objects. A framework is often responsible for creating these objects as well.

What does the author here mean by the above quote?
What does the framework represent, and "how" is it responsible for creating these objects as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not trivial to discuss this at such a general level. I'll try to.

Usually a framework provides a set of abstract classes that are used in the framework's code, but whose binding is only resolved at runtime.

The framework calls methods of instances of these classes, which you are responsible to implement in your code.

That is, in your code you will extend such classes, and "fill in the blanks".

The glue between your code and the framework's code is the contract defined by such abstract classes (or interfaces, fwiw): the framework knows that a given method takes parameters of type K, and return type T, thus can call it safely, assuming its semantic will be respected by the implementor.

On the other hand, when you implement the method, you implicitly accept the contract attached to it and implement it respecting the semantics associated with it.

Hope it was clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

A software framework in the OOP world is a set of classes that provide basic functionality that a programmer can then use and extend to create an application.  Let's take a trivial example of an framework for developing cars.  It might have an abstract class called automobile that does not implement a full car but might provide basic methods for forward, stop and reverse.  There could be another set of classes for wheels.  Automobile classes have wheels (contains relationship) and that relationship could be defined in the abstract automobile class.  Therefore the framework "maintains relationships between objects."

But to use the abstract automobile class you would need to create a concrete class, for example a Ford pickup truck or a Ferrari sports car.  This is where you can use the factory design pattern to create concrete instances of these types of vehicles.  The factory class creates specific instance of different types of automobiles for the framework to use.  But in many cases the framework will not care if it is a Ford or a Ferrari, it just wants to invoke the methods for forward, stop and reverse.  How they are actually implemented (for example the Ferrari can accelerate much faster than the Ford) is of no concern to the framework.  Using the factory class encapsulates these details from the framework.  When it says, "A framework is often responsible for creating these objects as well" it is referring to the fact that the framework can provide a basic factory for automobiles that can be extended to add your own concrete implementations of automobiles.